# Dictionary mapping in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dictionary with product line codes with brand names associated, I'm trying to map a new column named 'Brand' with the associated brand names from the dictionary, my issue is that when I output the file, I get partial returned;

```
line_codes = {1:'brand name1', 2:'brand name2', 'AD':'brand name3', 'MN':'brand name4'}

data = pd.read_csv('datafile.csv', names=['SKU','Descr','LineCode' 'Price','QTY']

data['Brand'] = data.LineCode.map(line_codes)

new_data = data
new_data.to_csv('datafile_out.csv', index=None)
```

Output:

[Output File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KvVp.png)

As you can see for some reason it's not bringing in all the brand names for the line code 1 but it brings in partial. I know these are mixed data types but even when trying to use low_memory=false or set the type, it still fails??

Comment: This is probably because your reading in LineCode as string not an integer.  Either cast LineCode as int using astype(int) or change dictionary to integer keys, such as '1':'brand name1', etc...

Comment: So I set all of my integers to strings in my dictionary, now it switched, the ones I was missing are coming in and the ones I had the first time are gone.

Comment: Hrm.. to me this seems that you are dealing with whitespace.  data.to_dict()... Look for white spaces around  your LineCode values such as ' 1' or '1 '.  Or you could leave your dictionary as integer keys  and cast LinceCode as integers too.  This will remove whitespace issues.

Comment: line_codes.update({str(k):v for k,v in list(line_codes.items())}) Thank you Patrick, that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem arises from the fact that pandas imports some of your cell contents as strings, others as numbers.

Your dictionary only matches the numbers of `1` and `2` - not the strings of `'1'` and `'2'`:

```
line_codes = {1:'brand name1', 2:'brand name2', 'AD':'brand name3', 'MN':'brand name4'}
print(line_codes)
```

You can add the "string"-versions of the keys to your dict like so:

```
line_codes.update({str(k):v for k,v in list(line_codes.items())})
print(line_codes)
```

Output:

```
# before
{1: 'brand name1', 2: 'brand name2', 'MN': 'brand name4', 'AD': 'brand name3'}

# after
{  1: 'brand name1',   2: 'brand name2', 'AD': 'brand name3', 'MN': 'brand name4', 
 '1': 'brand name1', '2': 'brand name2'}
```

That way both possible keys are present and your dataframe should substitute the keys correctly.